# What is the appropriate way to check an ability with conditions for CanCan in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

In my application, I have several user roles; customer, salesperson, admin, and superadmin. In my ability class, I've defined various abilities based on these roles.

The only role I currently have defined for a salesperson is as follows:

```
# Salesperson Abilities
if user.role == 'salesperson'
  can :create, User, :role => 'customer'
end
```

Unfortunately, the following check always returns true, allowing a salesperson to create any user, regardless of role:

```
can? :create, User, :role => @user.role
```

I've run a number of tests, verifying both the current user's role, and the role being created, and regardless of what role I place in the `:role` condition, the ability check always returns true. If I remove the ability altogether, or if I use a `cannot` definition, the check returns false, so I know that the abilities within the conditional are being applied.

Am I not defining or checking the ability conditions properly? Thanks.

---

### Update

I've noticed that if I attempt to authorize the ability using `authorize! :create, @user`, the conditions are applied. They are also applied if I define `load_and_authorize_resource` at the top of the controller class. It seems that these only fail when I attempt to use the `can?` method with conditions inside of a controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [documentation](http://rdoc.info/github/ryanb/cancan/CanCan/Ability) I found the following:

> IMPORTANT: Neither a hash of conditions or a block will be used when checking permission on a class.

In this case, the solution is to not check permissions on the Class but on an instance instead, e.g. `can? :create, @user` or `can? :create, User.new`

Answer (score 0):

This logic does not belong inside of an ability. The ability should define the rules for how objects are modified, not which data can be modified inside of these objects. This logic belongs in your User model, since it is handling the actual data of the model and how it is saved. Does this make sense?

Comment: I understand what you're suggesting, but in the [documentation for CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities/), under the "Hash of Conditions" heading, it demonstrates the practice of defining conditions that must exist within the object for the ability to return true.

Comment: Exactly, you just said why your approach will not work. When you post to create, the object does not exist yet, so how can you check conditions on it? That is why this belongs in the User model, not the ability. Your only option would be to pass in the params hash to your ability.